# Stripe connect payout - throws exceptions

Tags: .net, stripe-payments, payout

I'm working on a .net project.
I am trying to pay out some amount to my connected account.
I tried with amount  = 15

This is my account balance object.

```
"object": "balance",
    "available": [
      {
        "amount": 1929490,
        "currency": "aud",
        "sourceTypes": {
          "card": 1929490
        },
        "rawJObject": null,
        "stripeResponse": null
      }
    ],
    "connectReserved": [
      {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "aud",
        "sourceTypes": null,
        "rawJObject": null,
        "stripeResponse": null
      }
    ],
    "instantAvailable": [
      {
        "amount": 1200000,
        "currency": "aud",
        "sourceTypes": {
          "bankAccount": 0,
          "card": 1200000,
          "fpx": 0,
          "rawJObject": null,
          "stripeResponse": null
        },
        "rawJObject": null,
        "stripeResponse": null
      }
    ],
    "issuing": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "pending": [
      {
        "amount": 108924,
        "currency": "aud",
        "sourceTypes": {
          "card": 108924
        },
        "rawJObject": null,
        "stripeResponse": null
      }
    ],
```

I've tried some methods. I'll post them here.

Method 1: Connect account selected his bank account for payouts (NOT card) and check following request
[image: connect account setting - payout - bank account]
Request :

```
 var options = new PayoutCreateOptions
                {
                    // Destination = connectAccountId,
                    Description = description,
                    Method = "standard",// standard or instant
                    SourceType = "bank_account", // options are bank_account, card, or fpx
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "aud",
                    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ConnectAccountId", connectAccountId } },
                };

                var requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                requestOptions.StripeAccount = connectAccountId;

                var service = new PayoutService();
                return service.Create(options, requestOptions);
```

Response :
"You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account for this transfer. Your ACH balance is too low.  You can use the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance)."

Nethod 2:Connect account selected his bank account for payouts (NOT card) and check following request

```
var options = new PayoutCreateOptions
                {
                    // Destination = connectAccountId,
                    Description = description,
                    Method = "standard",// standard or instant
                    SourceType = "card", // options are bank_account, card, or fpx
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "aud",
                    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ConnectAccountId", connectAccountId } },
                };
```

Response:

"You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account for this transfer. Your card balance is too low.  You can use the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance)."

Method 3: Connect account selected his debit card for payouts (NOT bank account) and check the following request.

[image: connect account setting payout - card]

Request: is same as request of method 2.

Response:

"Method `standard` is not supported for payouts to debit cards."

Method 4:  Connect account selected his debit card for payouts (NOT bank account) and check the following request.

```
var options = new PayoutCreateOptions
                {
                    // Destination = connectAccountId,
                    Description = description,
                    Method = "instant",// standard or instant
                    SourceType = "card", // options are bank_account, card, or fpx
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "aud",
                    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ConnectAccountId", connectAccountId } },
                };
```

Response:

"You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account for this transfer. Your card balance is too low.  You can use the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance)."

Method 5:  Connect account selected his debit card for payouts (NOT bank account) and check the following request.

Request :

```
  var options = new PayoutCreateOptions
                {
                    // Destination = connectAccountId,
                    Description = description,
                    Method = "instant",// standard or instant
                    SourceType = "bank_account", // options are bank_account, card, or fpx
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "aud",
                    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ConnectAccountId", connectAccountId } },
                };
```

Response :

"You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account for this transfer. Your ACH balance is too low.  You can use the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance)."

I'm tired of searching for the reason for these issues. I want to payout the amount to Connect's bank account.  Please help me.

---

**Updated question** :

According to Lucky's answer, I've updated my code.

1. First I transferred the amount to the connect account and tried to payout.

```
 var options = new TransferCreateOptions
                {
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "aud",
                    Destination = connectAccountId,
                    Description = description,
                    // SourceType = "bank_account" //bank_account, card, or fpx  // This didn't works. got invalid source type error.
                };
                var service = new TransferService();
                return service.Create(options);
```

Balance in my connect account

```
 "available": [
      {
        "amount": 30,
        "currency": "aud",
        "sourceTypes": {
          "card": 30
        },
        "rawJObject": null,
        "stripeResponse": null
      }
    ],
    "connectReserved": null,
    "instantAvailable": [
      {
        "amount": 30,
        "currency": "aud",
        "sourceTypes": {
          "bankAccount": 0,
          "card": 30,
          "fpx": 0,
          "rawJObject": null,
          "stripeResponse": null
        },
        "rawJObject": null,
        "stripeResponse": null
      }
    ],
    "issuing": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "pending": [
      {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "aud",
        "sourceTypes": {
          "card": 0
        },
        "rawJObject": null,
        "stripeResponse": null
      }
```

**Method 1: try to pay out to the bank _account**

```
  var options = new PayoutCreateOptions
                {
                    // Destination = connectAccountId,
                    Description = description,
                    Method = "standard",// standard or instant
                    SourceType = "bank_account", // options are bank_account, card, or fpx
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "aud",
                    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ConnectAccountId", connectAccountId } },
                };

                var requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                requestOptions.StripeAccount = connectAccountId;

                var service = new PayoutService();
                return service.Create(options, requestOptions);
```

**This didn't work. Got the same insufficient error.**

Method 2:
**Payout to connects card - worked**

```
    var options = new PayoutCreateOptions
                {
                    // Destination = connectAccountId,
                    Description = description,
                    Method = "standard",// standard or instant
                    SourceType = "card", // options are bank_account, card, or fpx
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "aud",
                    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ConnectAccountId", connectAccountId } },
                };
```

After the payout, Connect acc's dashboard looks like this.
[image: last 2 Transcation summary]
[image: summary]
[image: last4]

**What does "Settled" mean?
The transactions with "0.15dolar" are only Transfer (Payout failed at that time)
0.48 dolar one is Transfer and payout are succeeded.**

**How my connect account holder will know these differences?
0.48 is in minus amount What does it mean?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the funds are in your platform's balance. They need to be in your connected account's balance for you to make a payout.

To clarify:

- A Payout is a transfer of funds between the Stripe account's balance and a bank account connected to that account.
- A Transfer is a transfer of funds between Stripe accounts' balance.

If you have `available` funds in your platform balance, you can make a payout to the bank account connected to your platform.
If you want to make a payout to the bank account connected to your connected account, you need `available` funds in the connected account's balance.

With that in mind:

- Check the balance for your platform (optional, you already did this)
  https://docs.stripe.com/api/balance/balance_retrieve
- Create a Transfer from your platform to your connected account:
  https://docs.stripe.com/api/transfers/create
- Check the balance for your connected account (same as above with the `stripeAccount` header)
- Create your payout, with the `stripeAccount` header and bank account / card ID as `destination`.
  `source_type` should be card but doesn't need to be specified. In fact I don't think `destination` does either, provided the connected account only has one valid external_account / you want to use the default one.